# How do I see where a folder was copied from?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a folder copied from somewhere on my computer. However, I don't know where it came from. Where do I find out where it was copied from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless it was *just* moved there, by Windows Explorer. If moved any other way, you won't be able to (usually), but you can try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to try the Undo Move command. Again, it has to be the last thing you did, and only if done through Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

If it was copied and not just moved, you can do a full search using the folder name or the name of something inside the folder. Windows: start key then start typing. OSX: open a Finder window and use the search box.